# "Скепсис" или "скептицизм"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, синонимы

Буквально только что понадобилось охарактеризовать моего горячо любимого друга, который относится ко всему предвзято, с заведомой критичностью, или, скорее, отрицательно. Уж не знаю, в какой степени, но принадлежность его к разряду скептиков, я думаю, нельзя отрицать. Вот тут-то я и задалась вопросом: мой друг, он полон обыденного "скепсиса" или "скептицизма"? Словари говорят, что эти слова являются синонимами, но ведь есть какое-то различие между этими словами?

Comment: Думаю, что скепсис это более рациональное мышление для разделение правды и лжи. А скептик это первоначальное однозначное недоверие.

Comment: По-вашему скептик — не человек, а некая реакция?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы не сказал, что это синонимы.
[Скептизцизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) - направление в философии. По сути - это научный термин, описывающий определенное мировоззрение.
Скепсис - почти бытовая форма слова, характеризующая определенные чувства, эмоции.
И применяют их, как правило, несколько по-разному:
**"полон скепсиса" в отношении чего-либо**
но
**"проявлять скептицизм" в отношении чего-либо**
Впрочем, если использовать эти слова в качестве синонимов, то вряд ли это будет такой уж большой проблемой.